# Search on variable fields with multiple match types

Tags: c#, sql-server

**Question:**

How can I build a search like this in .NET with SQL Server?  Notice the "Score", and "Max" columns.  (These are not my terms.  "Max" appears to represent the maximum value for a query, and "Score" represents the value achieved by the search, which is less than or equal to the "Max".)

This is how the input to the search appears:
[image]

This search included the SSN:
[image]

This search did not include the SSN:
[image]

**Details:**

1. The user may input one or more of these fields: name_first (varchar(254)), name_middle (varchar(254)), name_last (varchar(254)), date_of_birth (date), social_security_number (varchar(50)), sex (char(1)), ABO_blood_type (varchar(2)), Rh_blood_type (varchar(3)).
2. The match may be a partial match such as a name.  It may also allow only an exact match such as male/female.
3. Different fields may matter more than others.  For example, a complete match for the social security number is more specific than a match on gender.

**Ideas**

1. The [Soundex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx) function may help for name matching
2. The SSN match should override all the other fields because it is the most specific.  In the example, it increases the Max/Score values relative to a match on all fields except the SSN.
3. It is interesting the unmatched SSN appears to contain "No Info" when in fact it did not match the search criteria.
4. Without an alternative, should I make up some type of scoring scheme?

Otherwise, I'm not sure where to start.  Thank you!

Comment: Have you designed a table to hold the data being searched?

Comment: try with `like` here is definition: [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/like.php)

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is a little bit too broad for StackOverflow. I suggest you try something, anything, and keep trying until you run into an actual roadblock that you cannot overcome. Then post your code and the error you get. You are much more likely to get help from this site that way.

Comment: Please explain the relationship between "Score" and "Max".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer does not attempt to represent a complete solution, rather a few hints on how to start.

1. I would imagine a stored procedure, which purpose is to query the underlying data table(s) according to provided conditions.
2. For each form field there is one parameter given. So for example `@name_first varchar(254)` would represent relevant form field. What is important is that `NULL` value passed into a stored procedure indicates that a particular form field was not supplied (or *ANY* was chosen).
3. For each row in the dataset being searched a *score* would be calculated. The exact formula is up to you, but the general rule could be that

   - when given parameter was `NULL` then result for field is zero
   - the same when the column value does not match
   - when the field matches - result is some number of points
   - point from particular conditions are summed up in order to calculate row score

Example:

```
select ...,
    case
      when name_first == @name_first then 100 --exact match
    else
      case
        when name_first like '%'+@name_first+'%' then 50 --partial match
      else
        0 --either @name_first is null or column does not match
      end
    end
    +
    case
      when sex == @sex then 150
    else
      0
    end
    +
    ...
    --when SSN matches add up a huge score such as 900
from <dataset>
```

4. The final result would contain only those rows, that provide *score* above some minimum number (i.e. 1).
5. As for masking SSN this is as simple as (in `SELECT` clause)

> ```
> ...
> case when @social_security_number = social_security_number then
> social_security_number else '-' end as social_security_number
> ...
> ```

I cannot deduce the relationship between `Score` and `Max`. More complicated condition expression would be needed for the date of birth field. Also whether the score is calculated in subquery or cross-applied is a question of how to write all required conditions in a readable and performant way. Too little data was given for any useful hints about this.